# How to play blu ray .mkv files on ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: blu-ray

How to play blu ray .mkv files on Linux?
e.g:1080p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-NTb.mkv

Comment: Have you tried VLC? It plays `.mkv` files with many formats.

Answer (score 3):

Install VLC and its Blu-ray support on Ubuntu.

Open a terminal window and run the following commands in order. You can copy and paste them into a terminal window using your mouse.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc libaacs0 libbluray-bdj libbluray1

mkdir -p ~/.config/aacs/

cd ~/.config/aacs/
wget --no-check-certificate http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg
```

If you get "Package 'libbluray1' has no installation candidate" message, try to intall the libbluray2 library.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc libaacs0 libbluray-bdj libbluray2
```

Comment: The idea is great, but I got "Issued certificate has expired.", so you need to pass `--no-check-certificate` to `wget` (it is some-kind-of insecure, but allows to download the file).

Comment: @N0rbert thanks. Added into answer. This reference might also be useful from superuser https://superuser.com/a/508697/856934

Comment: Edited answer again for readability and reproducibility.

Comment: Sadly, this currently doesn't work (check date). Getting "No valid processing key found in AACS config file." in VLC Error dialog pop-up. Similar problem for solutions with said key on Windows 10.

Comment: @N0rbert, I am getting: `E: Package 'libbluray1' has no installation candidate` error. How to fix it? OS version: `$ uname -a
Linux alex-G7-7700 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and retry. The [*libbluray1* package is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libbluray1&searchon=names) only for 16.04 LTS.