# How to decode play Blu Ray .mkv video format file?

Tags: video, codecs, multimedia, blu-ray

System OS version & player media:Ubuntu 20.04 TLS amd64 of VLC&Kodi ;Windows 10x64 of PotPlayer

e.g:[Rick and Morty S01 1080p BluRay DD5.1 x264-NTb](https://pan.lifan.ooo/%E3%80%90%E5%8A%A8%E6%BC%AB%E3%80%91/Rick.and.Morty.S01.1080p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-NTb/Rick.and.Morty.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.DD5.1.x264-NTb.mkv)

[How to play blu ray .mkv files on ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258745/how-to-play-blu-ray-mkv-files-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

Installed VLC and its Blu-ray support on Ubuntu.

I have used both Ubuntu and Windows and cannot parse the video.

How can I do codec play for mkv video?

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, also desktop & program you will use to view file.

Comment: Depends on what you are planning on doing with the file.  If you just want to watch it VLC Player should be enough.  If you want to change it to a different format like .m4v, etc Handbrake does a great job of converting.

Comment: VLC..... my cyber security spidey sense got triggered by that link when I hovered... be careful

Comment: System OS version & player media:Ubuntu 20.04 TLS amd64 of VLC ;Windows 10x64 of PotPlayer.
Both Ubuntu and Windows have been used and cannot parse play videos.

Comment: If you've done everything from the other links then maybe the file is bad. Have you tried a different .mkv?

Comment: Perhaps try Kodi instead

Comment: yes, can't parse video information ;
You can download it in the virtual machine and check the problem

Comment: Probably a fake file.

Comment: nah, i'm gonna pass on downloading that... you can upload the output if you want someone to look at it.

Comment: I downloaded them completely, and the file size is larger than the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install VLC player.

Other good ones are mplayer, kmplayer, smplayer, miro, mpv etc.

Also, you can check the media with `mediainfo --fullscan input.mkv`

Comment: Both Ubuntu and Windows have been used and cannot parse play videos.
System OS version & player media:Ubuntu 20.04 TLS amd64 of VLC ;Windows 10x64 of PotPlayer.

Comment: Then it's likely that they are either corrupt, compressed or encrypted. What is the output of the `file` command on each of the files?

Comment: The command output information of each file is not clear,You can download it in the virtual machine and check the problem